# Is secure to expose Firebase push ID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For a chat app I build, I want to use the autogenerated ID by Firebase realtime database push as messages identifier. Is secure (or effective) to use this ID as HTML attribute for later get it with JS and edit specific message by ID ?

I thought about using the timestamp, but maybe the ID is more unique. I also thought about using the message counter, but the application will have a somewhat high traffic, so I would have to use firebase transactions to avoid conflict when generating the counter, and store the number of messages in another object to avoid having to get the number in each query.

Comment: Please update your question with code you have tried and your one challenge with that so we can assist you in fixing it.

Comment: Yes it it safe to expose these to the UI. Just make sure to set security rules (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security ) to allow or deny access

Comment: What is your definition of "secure"?  Please edit the question to be more specific about what your concern is, along with your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.